# Throw an exception if a block was not extended - Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a `base.html` that has blocks in it for example:

```
{% block somecontent %} {% endblock %}
```

If another html extends this `base.html` it has the ability to extend `somecontent` block OR not.

My question is, is there a way for a the template to throw an exception if the `somecontent` was **not** extended?

This will prevent from forgetting to extend the `somecontent` block

Thanks

Comment: out of curiosity why do you need that?

Comment: I want to include dynamic open graph contents - eg title, image, description etc and I sometimes forget

Answer (score 2):

It sounds more like you might need to change your way of working, start by adding the blocks first before you do anything

If you're using PyCharm you can change the default html template to be one that creates an outline for a page that extends from the base. I'm sure other IDE's have similar.

But in answer to your question

> is there a way for a the template to throw an exception if the somecontent was not extended?

No not really, you could make the default block include some template code that will *always* error

For example the following should throw a `NoReverseMatch`

```
{% block content %}{% url 'fake_url' %}{% endblock %}
```

but this won't be a very clear exception, may be confusing for other developers, and if forgotten, will make your customer see an error page for something that wasn't their fault.

You may also eventually find a point where you don't always want to show the block to be shown.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - from my understanding to your answer - I am already doing that (Creating a base.html with all the blocks in it - then I create other HTML files to extend that base.html)

Comment: I am currently using PyCharm IDE, how is that done? Sounds very convenient.

Comment: @jonprasetyo - My point is you can't forget to add them if you add them as the first thing you do

Comment: @jonprasetyo - File > Settings > Editor > File and Code Templates

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?

```
{% block somecontent %} 
  <script>
    alert("somecontent missing");
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

I haven't tested it. But it should give an alert when the page loads.

Comment: Yes it works - but i am looking for an exception. Thanks for your answer